# Band limited discrete signals division

Tags: aliasing, digital, analog

If I take two analog, band limited signals $ x(t) $ and $ y(t) $ with non-zero $y(t)$ I can define the division:
$$
 z(t) = \frac{x(t)}{y(t)} 
$$

In general $z(t)$ may have a very wide bandwidth, also if the two signals had a small bandwidth.

I ideally may lowpass filter out a limited band part of $z(t)$ and make a discrete version $ z[n] $ without aliasing.

If I instead make division from the discrete versions $ x[n] $ and $ y[n] $ (they are band limited so I can also have a sampled discrete version that completely describe them) the result can be very different from the other discrete version $ z[n] $ after the lowpass antialias filter, in fact I have aliasing.

Is there a way to estimate in digital domain the $ z[n] $ that I would obtain making the division in analog domain and filtering out the lowpass part?

Comment: as you've noticed, $z$ can be quite problematic. The harsh truth is that you very rarely find the ratio of two signals actually be calculated in signal processing, because that's a very unstable operation ($z$ is undefined whenever $y(t)=0$, and it is *extremely* sensitive to noise when $y$ is small). So, I doubt your low-pass filtered $z$ makes any sense in practice – can you elaborate where you meet that problem? maybe from that context, conditions arise that make answering your question easier.

Comment: Your $z$ might not even have defined energy/mean.  For example, if $x$ and $y$ are filtered noise, their values will follow a Gaussian distribution, so the ratio would follow a Cauchy distribution, which doesn't have mean/variance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Properties

Comment: Marcus Muller, I know this, but I often found this situation, for example from data derived from sensors that phisically should be divided, I often see aliasing in these operations so I'm looking for a quite general solution for these situations. We can also neglect noise for a theoretical answer.

Comment: @Andrea again, a sensible approach depends on the nature of your sensor signal; Cloudfeet gave an excellent example in which way some things will lead to useless data, but others will not; noise is not the only Gaussian-shaped thing; in fact, we model very many sensor observation as Gaussian. Since division is not a linear operation, it doesn't have a z-transform; you need to come up with an estimator that is specific to your signal model, and even more importantly, *what* you plan to do with the output.

Comment: @Andrea also, I've *never* (literally, never) seen an analog division; that's something that is pretty hard to implement (Probably, taking the logarithms of the absolute input signals, then subtracting then, then an exponential function, then if necessary sign reversal). It's really not too much of a useful operation, overall, and I'd be suprised if it makes *all* too much sense to model that directly. The cases where we *do* see operations that turn out to be divisions, it's usually control loops controlling the product of two things, and that's something you'd model differently altogether.

Comment: @Marcus with analog I means the mathematics and ideal signal R ->R

Comment: Btw I think that I have found a simple good way to estimate, I will post when I will try it

Comment: Let me know of that estimator! In general $z$ isn't band-limitable at all, so I'd be really surprised if you had an estimator that had a finite error.

Comment: //with analog I means the mathematics and ideal signal $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$// .............  Andrea, Analog Devices (same company that makes the SHArC) used to do analog signal process (probably still do, but now it's a small part of the company) and had these multiplier chips that you can put in the feedback loop of an op amp and make a divider out of it.  But they hit the rails with $y(t)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an estimator that can work for a lot of similar situations, the idea is that you can rewrite the division:
$$ x(t) = z(t) \cdot y(t) \tag1$$
The problem now is to estimate $ z(t) $ that solves the equation.
One can start to find a constant coefficient that minimize the *2-norm*. This coefficient will be the [*linear regression slope without intercept term*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Simple_linear_regression_without_the_intercept_term_(single_regressor)) ($\beta$), hence you can write an approximation of $ z(t) $ that minimize the 2-norm:
$$ x(t) \approx \beta \cdot y(t)\tag2 $$
This estimator is constant, hence it is *band limited*, and you can estimate the same $ \beta $ from the sampled data, in fact be valid that
$$ x[n] \approx \beta \cdot y[n]\tag3 $$

Obviously this estimation is quite useless but you can extend this approach in a kind of *FIR* way , first.
You could make a *rectangular window* and estimate the *linear regression slope* on $N$ elements.

$$ x[n] \approx \beta(x[(n-N),..,N], y[(n-N),..,n]) \cdot y[n] \tag4$$

I don't like a lot this estimator but should limit aliasing if $ N $ is  large enough.

I instead prefer an *IIR* like approach, using an *exponential window*. You can do this using a *0-order* [*RLS* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter). You can choose a bandwidth choosing the *forgetting factor* $ \lambda = e^{-\frac{1}{W_s}}$,
where $ W_s $ is the width in samples of the exponential window, that can be expressed in function of cut off pulsation ($\omega_c$) using the relation

$$ W_s = \frac{f_s}{\omega_c} \tag 5$$
where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency.

With *RLS* you can estimate the slope $\beta$ in a *time-variant* way, with a limited band in discrete domain, where the bandwidth is limited by $ \omega_c $. Note that in this case (*0-order*) *RLS* becomes a *scalar* problem so it is very easy to implement.

Comment: "but should limit aliasing": your problem is that the error between $\beta$ and $z[n]$ can get arbitrarily large in your equation $(4)$, because the ratio of two band-limited signal can (and will) have singularities at isolated points, and you can't predict where they lie, and how close you get to them with your sampling instants!

Comment: Yes, but the fact is that when someone divides signals in reality it's probable that he would like to estimate the signal that solves the product equation. And if there is a phisical meaning this is the correct solution.

Comment: Then it's true that a band limited signal that make division can have an arbitrary large error, but it's inevitable, and in discrete domain you can't do better

Comment: Good news! You *can* be better, namely by specifying the metric for which you optimize – it's very literally the difference between a zero-forcing frequency domain equalizer and an MMSE equalizer :) That's why I was pestering you so much about what you use this for, what this signal is: your approach on its own has little utility. Your approach with a good metric is what we do, but the metric depends on the application.

Comment: I propose 2-norm because it's the most natural and it's easy to minimize, you can change the norm if you know what you exactly need. For physical data from sensors typically 2-norm works very well

Comment: I do agree it feels very natural. I do not agree to your assertion that it will work well for any sensor data, but I think we've had that disagreement before :)

Comment: Not "any data", I don't think so either. For typical data of for example a typical control systems probably yes.

Comment: Hm! What's "typical" data to you? To me, it's zero-mean band-limited data, and it really doesn't fit well with that!

Comment: Because, think about it: if x and y are uncorrelated, then the expectation of their product is 0; but their ratio, by no means, has to be close to zero for all times – but that's exactly what your averaging approach will give you.

Comment: Now, the problem I have with you saying "typically": This is *exactly* the kind of signals you'd care about, uncorrelated ones – if they were correlated, the ratio would carry little information, would it. One place where the communications engineer encounters the qoutient of the I and Q signal is in PSK demodulation, and esp. in modelling the noisy PSK symbol error rate. It's mathematically pretty challenging to *model* it, and it seems to be numerically impossible to do it for noisy realizations, which is exactly why no PSK demodulator is based on the otherwise obvious $\arctan (I/Q)$.

Comment: Typical I mean when you want to make a division, for example you want to estimate same rate, for example massOut/gasIn. If the problem is itself well defined it means that a solution should exists

Comment: To estimate arctan ratio I see often PLLs or similar, that are solutions quite similar to RLS that I proposed

Comment: Cool, so that's now a different class of signals than what I thought about :) That's why I was asking you to specify which signal you think about so many times!

Comment: happy to have clarified :)